# WCF. How to check if credentials are valid on client side?

Tags: wcf, windows-authentication

I have a WCF service with Windows authentication. 
On the client side, I want to show a login form for a user. And how can I check if the entered credentials are valid? 
The only way I've found - call a method and check if it fails. Is there a better way?

Comment: You can only check credentials by submitting them to the party who knows if they are correct.

Comment: You will catch an authentication error in TryCatch statement when you call the service with the wrong credential. you could handle it in the Catch statement.

Comment: @AbrahamQian, I do this way. But I should call a business logic method. It seems not to be the best way.

Comment: Is your WCF service in a different domain to your clients?